# MacPorts: What does "Port Health" mean?

Tags: install, macports

I have an old Mac (El Capitan) and `MacPorts` was suggested in other post in this same network to accomplish some updates for some tools/software. I've already watched some videos about how to install and basic commands.

Just to prior to install into the OS - I did realise for example that for `MySQL 8` exists in its official home page the version 8.0.28 and in MacPorts 8.0.27 as follows:

- [mysql8](https://ports.macports.org/port/mysql8/details/)
- [mysql8-server](https://ports.macports.org/port/mysql8-server/details/)

For each link, in the right part, exists the **Port Health** section, and some `OSX` versions has green and other red colors.

- What does `Port Health` mean?

I am with the assumption - *correct me if I am wrong* - that does not exist MySQL 8.0.27 available  for El Capitan (because it is in red).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port Health is a report on what the buildbots have built.

buildbots are the machines that Macports runs and build binaries from the port files so that you can download the binaries rather than have to compile the source yourself

The web page shows a tick or cross whether the build worked or not. There are entries with a question mark `?`. These are where no build has been attempted yet. This is most obvious with Ventura, as of 29/11/02 there is no arm builder for this but there is a recent x86_64 builder, go ? for all arm builds and older Intel builds but later have a tick or cross. ? also shows up for some Leopard cases.

So in this case it tells you that the build worked for all macOS/OSX from High Sierra onwards.

The links from each OS name go to the fuller report that the buildbots make, however these logs are deleted after a time and so as the mysql8 portfiles and source have not changed recently then they have been deleted. The builds were made in October/November last year from [here](https://ports.macports.org/port/mysql8/builds/)

The red mark for El Capitan says that the buildbots could not build it. Unfortunately as no recent change there is no log to show why. I would try to install it, as there is no binary macports will try to build it and your local logs will show what the issue is. This can be reported to [trac.macports.org](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Tickets) You might get lucky and someone be able to fix it.

Comment: Other reason about to use MacPorts (and before Homebrew) is avoid do a manual build (make install) it according with many suggestions learned through Linux (`sudo apt`) - therefore I am not able to use MySQL - but yes Bash - I need do an upgrade - https://ports.macports.org/port/bash/details/

Comment: Does apt support Linux kernals 10 years old?

Comment: I mean, in Ubuntu - is suggested use the official repositories (`sudo apt instal something`) instead of do a _manual_ `make` and `install`

Comment: Yes and that is true for Homebrew and Macports - the issue is that does apt just provide and use the latest version of Linux or can it provide e.g. mysql to run on a 10 year old kernal or do you have to update the kernal through apt as well?

Comment: No, my situation is only for MacOS - I just did do a comparison/mention of Linux about to not use `make` and `install`  - I need upgrade my Bash on MacOS and other tools such as MySQL

Comment: The point I am asking is are you comparing like with like. ie Linux apt has the same issues as Macports

Comment: Agree, but is easier update the OS release in Ubuntu than on MacOS - because MacOS is tight with its own hardware - Linux is more flexible with old hardware. If I try to upgrade my old Mac (2012) with the latest OS I am assuming it is going to be slower ... It did happen to me once.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included an explanation of the "?" status, e.g. [here](https://ports.macports.org/port/meld/details/) currently has "?" for the oldest (PowerPC legacy) and newest (Ventura) variants.

Comment: I suspect that ? means  a build has not been attempted yet. The ventura builders are very new